# .htaccess rewrite won't load css in a few occasions

Tags: mod-rewrite

This is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
#RewriteRule (.*)/?$ $1\.php [L]
RewriteRule profile/ profile.php
RewriteRule profile profile.php
```

i'm a bit new at this, but when I go to localhost/profile, everything loads fine, but when I go to localhost/profile/ the actual page loads, but the css doesn't load, I gotta manually change it to /style.css for it to load, does anyone know how I can do this while making the / at the end optional (without having to put my entire domain or the absolute path)? Thanks.

Comment: u gotta give the original path for your css

Comment: ¿What do you want to load, style.css or profile.php? The rule set  indicates is the last one and I guess that one in turn calls the first one, but I am just guessing. Hard to understand what happens when `"...everything loads fine..."`

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA no external files will load, such as style.css nor any images, because it thinks its a new directory when i do localhost/profile/, but it works perfectly on localhost/profile, i just don't want to go changing everything to /style.css instead of style.css, it can get real messy, so i'd just like to get a new rewrite rule that works without making a "new directory"

Comment: @user1925957 Then, style.css doesn't load with a trailing slash URI because the path to the file when it is called is wrong. Maybe this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) will help.

Answer (score 1):

you can Try this
 `<? echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'."http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."../style.css".'" />' ?>`

But this is not the best solution. What you can do is you can define a global variable use that to give absoluete paths. i.e

```
<?php 
//at the beginning of your page
define('LINK',"http://localhost/");

//for your css href
echo LINK."style.css";
```

Note: The path is assumption as i do not know your folder structure.

Comment: I tried that, changed all my links manually in every file, and made things worse, when I went to /profile/, it loaded fine, just that on the side bar, thats supposed to go to /profile/ in the first place, it was going to /profile/profile/, just got too messy, guess I won't be using the /profile/ url, just /profile, I wish there was an easier way to do all this just by mod_rewrite

Comment: @user1925957 I have developed projects with mod_rewrite and i have used absolute pathing. Worked fine for me evry time.